# Selecting COUNT from MySQL table by first letter of a column

Tags: php, mysql, count

What I'm trying to do is select all first letters in a column and get a COUNT of how many times each letter occurs. So far I'm able to get the count of each letter but not sure how to output the letters themselves.

Query: `SELECT COUNT(SUBSTRING(`last_name`, 1, 1)) as letter FROM users GROUP BY SUBSTRING(`last_name`, 1, 1);`

Output:

```
letter
------
0
4
1
5
1
1
13
1
74
2
2
8
1
```

How do I get the letters next to the numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(last_name, 1, 1) as letter, count(*) as total FROM users 
          GROUP BY SUBSTRING(last_name, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

As straight forward as possible;

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING(last_name,1,1) as letter, 
  COUNT(last_name) AS cnt 
  FROM users 
  GROUP BY SUBSTRING(last_name, 1, 1);
```

Live demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f295/10).